# Can you perform a Sql Bulk Insert of a Geometry data type with entity framework 2.2 with NetTopologySuite?

Tags: spatial, bulkinsert, entity-framework-core-2.2

I'm using EF net core 2.2 and NetTopologySuite and trying to merge some attribute data with the associated geometry data.  The attribute data is in text file format, and I can read that in fine.  The geometry data is in its own table, and I can read that from the MS-Sql server just fine.  The linq join works fine and this process completes in ~11 seconds.

The relevant code lines are:

The goal is to write the newly created list back into its own table in MS-Sql, and if I foreach over the loop the individual items will write to the table (45 min later).  Bulk insert (using a dataadapter method or EFCore.Bulkinsert methods both fail -- they don't seem to want to put the geometry type into the table.

```
    //  This starts the update process.
            //  Truncate the table (its faster).
            Console.WriteLine("Beginning data update");
            context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("Truncate table Tax_Parcels");

            //  context.BulkInsert(result);  This is generating an error on insert from nettopologysuite


            /*
             * Also generates error on insert.  I'm thinking bulk insert will have to wait to net core 3 releases ...
             * 
            var objBulk = new BulkUploadToSql<Parcel>()
            {
                InternalStore = parcels,
                TableName = "BOA_Staging",
                CommitBatchSize = 10000,
                ConnectionString = "Data Source=localhost;Initial catalog=<deleted>; UseTrustedConnection=True;"
            };

            objBulk.Commit();

           */
           //  standard  add works, but takes 45 min to process records ><

            int counter = 0;
            int loop = 0;

            foreach(var item in result)
            {
                context.Add(item);
                counter++;
                if (counter > 1000)
                {
                    context.SaveChanges();                    
                    counter = 0;
                    loop++;
                    Console.WriteLine("I've added " + loop.ToString() + "000 Records so far");
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Done.  I've added " + loop.ToString() + counter.ToString("{0,3}") + " Records.");
            context.SaveChanges();      

            Console.WriteLine("Data update complete");
```

Answer (score 1):

Workaround:

1. Make a staging table for the attributes and load the text file data into a SQL table. Do any conversions needed during the import process.
2. Create a view to join the table with the geometry field to the attribute table.
3. Create a combined view table (if you don't have one already)
4. Create a stored procedure to insert the data from the view into the combined view table.
5. In the update program, use `context.Database.ExecuteSql` to truncate the staging table and combined view table, run the update to the staging table to load the new data, then trigger the stored procedure to update the combined view table.

Stats:

- Using `EF.Add()` - 45 min.
- Using workaround above 45 sec.